# Power BI import python issue

Tags: python

Im trying to use python to import my csv file into Power BI but this error showed? What should I do? I have set all the paths for my python app and the IDE as well

Details: "ADO.NET: A problem occurred while processing your Python script.
Here are the technical details: Access is denied"

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to try and do this?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. The code is just two lines

Import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv(...)
print(dataset)

The same code copied and pasted works in VS Code. I wonder if it's the same for OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I fixed it by installing python in a path that contains only Unicode characters. e.g. d:\tools\python3 . Installing python from MS stores seems to put python in a path that is not compliant.

See power BI documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts#install-python

> Blockquote
> The current Python scripting release supports Unicode characters and spaces in the installation path.
> Blockquote